# Remove the angular2 component's selector tag

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I have a user component for 2 templates. First template for users table, second one for a user page. I select which template to use by `role` attribute.

First example of using:

```
<table>
    <tr user *ngFor="let user of users" [user]="user" role="UserTableItem"></tr>
</table>
```

In another one template I use my component like this:

```
<div user [user]="user" role="UserCard"></div>
```

So, my `user` component template:

```
// user.template.html

<user-card [user]="user" *ngIf="role === 'UserCard'"></user-card>
<user-list-item [user]="user" *ngIf="role === 'UserListItem'"></user-list-item>
```

As we can see, here two components `user-card` and `user-list-item`. `user-card` contains `div` blocks, `user-list-item` contains `td` blocks. And  table crashed because I have a `<user-list-item>` block inside and my table looks like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <user-list-item>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </user-list-item>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I solve my problem and get table like this?

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**UPD:**

My `user` component:

```
// user.component.ts

import { Component, Input, Inject, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { UserCard } from './userCard.component';
import { UserListItem } from './userListItem.component';

@Component({
  selector: '[user]',
  templateUrl: './user.template.html',
  directives: [UserCard, UserListItem]
})
export class User {
  @Input() user:any = null;
  role:string;

  constructor(
    @Attribute('role') role) {
    this.role = role;
  }
}
```

`userListItem.template.html`:

```
<td>
    {{user.id}}
</td>

<td>
    <img src="{{user.avatarUrl160}}" alt="User profile picture" width="160">
</td>
// ...
```

`userCard.template.html`:

```
<div class="card card-block" *ngIf="user">
    <h4 class="card-title">
        User #{{user.id}}
        <span class="tag tag-success" *ngIf="!user.isBanned">Active</span>
        <span class="tag tag-danger" *ngIf="user.isBanned">Banned</span>
        <span class="tag tag-danger" *ngIf="user.isDeleted">Deleted</span>
    </h4>
    <p>
        <img width="340" src="{{user.avatarUrl160}}">
    // ...
</div>

<div class="card card-block" *ngIf="user">
    <span class="text-muted">Company: </span> {{user.company.name}}<br>
    <span class="text-muted">Company logo: </span>
    // ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find your question a bit confusing but I guess what you want is an attribute selector

```
@Component({
  selector: '[user-list-item]',
  ...
})
export class UserListItem { ... }
```

and instead of

```
<user-card [user]="user" *ngIf="role === 'UserCard'"></user-card>
<user-list-item [user]="user" *ngIf="role === 'UserListItem'"></user-list-item>
```

use

```
<td user-card [user]="user" *ngIf="role === 'UserCard'"></td>
<td user-list-item [user]="user" *ngIf="role === 'UserListItem'"></td>
```

Comment: But how I will use it here? `<table>
    <tr user *ngFor="let user of users" [user]="user" role="UserTableItem"></tr>
</table>` I can use `<tr><tr></tr></tr>`

Comment: As I said it was hard for me to get what exactly you try to accomplish from the snippets. Can you please post the complete component code so I can see what selectors you use for each component, what the template of what component exactly is. If there are `<ng-content>` or whatever.

Comment: Change user-card and user-list-item to use attribute selectors instead of elements selectors and use it like shown in my updated answer.

Comment: You also need to remove the `<td>` elements in your `user-list-item` component. I don't know how `user-card` fits in because there you don't have any `<td>`

Comment: `userCard.template.html` contains `div` blocks. I can't use `<user-card>` like `<td user-card>`. Also, I haven't problem with `<user-card>`. I have a problem with `<user-list-item>`. And again, I can't use `<td user-list-item>` from your example, cause in result I will get `<td><td></td></td>`

Comment: can we use attribute selector for bootstrap component?

Comment: @tsiro I think so. Should be easy to find out.